# Android Google Maps transition from portrait to landscape and vice versa

Tags: android

My application only displays the map on Google maps. My problem is when I change the position of my screen (the application I installed on my tablet), turning it there's a white screen that appears before displaying the map.

My configuration; res / layout / main.xml and res / layout-land / main.xml to switch from portrait to landscape mode.

What should add or do to resolve this behavior?

Comment: can you post your activity's onCreate and layouts? let's see if you're doing some excessive work there.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/map"
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

Comment: edit your question. there's not enough room in comments

Comment: @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
  try {
   initilizeMap();
   
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

Comment: private void initilizeMap(){
  if (googleMap == null) {
   googleMap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
   
   if (googleMap == null) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "impossible de créér googleMaps", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
   }
  }
 }
 
 @Override
 protected void onResume(){
  super.onResume();
  initilizeMap();
 }

Answer (score 0):

Since you have specified the map fragment in the layout file, you can safely find it using `findFragmentById` in `onCreate` like so:

```
MapFragment mMapFragment; // this is neither GoogleMap or MapView!

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mMapFragment = (MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    initializeMap();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // map init was already done in onCreate, will not do it twice
}
```

Then when you need the `GoogleMap` object you ask for it and have it delivered via a callback. When the callback executes, the map is guaranteed to be not null. This will work since Google Play services library v6.5.

```
private void initializeMap() {
    mMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            // googleMap will never be null here
            // do not store it in a variable, always make a getMapAsync call
            // do your map setup here
        }
    }
}
```

This is as quick as it gets so you shouldn't experience any flickering.

Note: In the original post you mentioned you had different layouts for portrait and landscape. If you really do, make sure both contain corresponding *fragment* IDs, otherwise you're bound to get exceptions. You also mentioned the layout was `main.xml` not `activity_main.xml` so make sure you use the layout you intended.

Comment: Is there any difference between your portrait and landscape layout? Please update the question with formatted code, don't post it in comments, it gets hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem reading this (Activity restart on rotation Android) [Activity restart on rotation Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android)